# Retornar ao try ao passar pelo catch

Tags: c#, exceção, try-catch

Em C# utilizando `try` `catch` ao entrar no `catch` é possível retornar ao `try` e executá-lo novamente?

Comment: Mas se deu erro é porque vai estar com problema, você quer gerar um loop desnecessário?

Comment: @novic o retorno ao Try seria por uma determinada quantidade de vezes, após isso o erro deve ser exibido normalmente.

Comment: O que vc quer repetir várias vezes? (Isso não deve ser feito dentro de um bloco try catch!)

Comment: Problemas de conexão por exemplo, mas daí vc faz um while dentro do próprio catxh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível, e geralmente é feito com [`goto`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements#the-goto-statement) ou `while`. Precisa tomar cuidado para controlar isso certo, muitas vezes é preciso ter interação com o usuário mostrando o erro, perguntando se quer continuar, pode ser necessário ter uma contagem para não continuar indefinidamente, e até mesmo colocar um limite de tentativas, sem falar em dar um tempo entre uma tentativa e outra. Aí vai do contexto em que está usando. E tem que tomar cuidado com operações que se repetem, pode não dar o resultado que espera. Também pode ser um problema dependendo do tipo da exceção lançada. Mas se quiser fazer e for tomar todos os cuidados (eu não recomendo sem experiência) de forma simplista pode fazer algo assim:

```
var tentou = 0;
while (tentou < 3) {
    try {
        //faz algo aqui que pode lançar a exceção que está capturando
        break;
    } catch (SuaExeption ex) {
        tentou++;
        //se quiser faça algo mais
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Retry.cs).

Se precisar de algo mais sofisticado pode querer seguir um padrão chamador [`retry`](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/retry-pattern-in-csharp/). [Opções mais simples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1563191/221800).